# Why is this $U_{a_1},...,a_m$ open in $\mathbb{R}_{n−m}$ for any choice of ${a_1, . . . , a_m}$?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis

Let $U ⊂ \mathbb{R}^n$ be open with respect to the usual topology. Fix any real numbers $a_1, . . . , a_m$ for $m < n$ and consider the set

$U_{a_1,...,a_m} :=
${ $(x_1, . . . , x_{n−m}) ∈ \mathbb{R}^{n−m} : (a_1, . . . , a_m, x_1, . . . , x_{n−m}) ∈ U$ }.

How could I use this to show that $U_{a_1},...,a_m$ is open in $\mathbb{R}_{n−m}$ for any choice of ${a_1, . . . , a_m}$?

Why isn't it just obvious from the fact that $U$ is open in $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Comment: If you are willing to accept that the euclidean topology on $\mathbb{R}^n$ coincides with the box topology of $\mathbb{R}^m\times \mathbb{R}^{n-m}$ this can be shown fairly easily.

Comment: Yes of course.  How can I show it using that fact then?

Comment: Is $(a_1, . . . , a_m, x_1, . . . , x_{n−m})$ equal to $\mathbb{R}^m$X$\mathbb{R}^{n-m}$ ?

Comment: Pick a point $(b_1,\cdots, b_{n-m})\in U_{a_1\cdots, a_m}$, then $(a_1,\cdots, a_m,b_1,\cdots, b_{n-m})\in U$. Use the definition of box topology to show that there exists an open set that contains $(b_1,\cdots, b_{n-m})$, that is also contained in $U_{a_1\cdots, a_m}$. Hence $U_{a_1\cdots, a_m}$ is open.

Comment: The definition says that for any Cartesian product of the topological spaces $X_i$, indexed by $i \in I$, the box topology on X is generated by the base

$B = \left\{ \prod_{i \in I} U_i \Big| U_i \text{ open in } X_i \right\}.$

If that generates a box topology, does that mean it is open?

Answer (score 1):

As I said in the comments, pick a point $(b_1,\cdots,b_{n-m})\in U_{a_1,\cdots,a_m}$. Then $(a_1,\cdots,a_m,b_1,\cdots,b_{n-m})\in U$. Since $U$ is open in the box topology $\mathbb{R}^m\times \mathbb{R}^{n-m}$, there exists open $U_1$ in $\mathbb{R}^m$ and open $U_2$ in $\mathbb{R}^{n-m}$ such that $$(a_1,\cdots,a_m,b_1,\cdots,b_{n-m})\in U_1\times U_2 \subseteq U. $$ However, every point of $(a_1,\cdots,a_m)\times U_2$ is of the form $(a_1,\cdots,a_m,x_1,\cdots, x_{n-m})$. So in particular, $$(b_1,\cdots,b_{n-m})\in U_2\subseteq U_{a_1,\cdots, a_m}.$$ Hence $U_{a_1,\cdots, a_m}$ is open.